# How to return strings that are trimmed automatically by ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, servicestack

I've noticed that when my entities are returned, the string values are padded to the number of characters of the field definition in the database, is the a setting to control this behavior?

Thank you,
Stephen

PostGreSQL 9.3
ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.4.0.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL only pads strings for fixed-size `CHAR(N)` columns, if you don't want this behavior you should instead use `VARCHAR(N)` columns instead - the recommended default for strings.

OrmLite also uses `VARCHAR` for strings when it's used to generate your table schema's, e.g:

```
db.CreateTable<Table>();
```

If dealing with legacy DB's, you can get OrmLite to automatically trim padded strings returned from RDBMS's with:

```
OrmLiteConfig.StringFilter = s => s.TrimEnd();
```